# How is Qdialog.exec() returning

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I know that `qdialog->exec()` only returns if `accept()` or `reject()` is called. However I am using the following code:

```
    mydialog* p =new mydialog(this);
    p->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal); 
    int return_code= p->exec() ;//Block 
    if(return_code==1)
    {
      //Called when `accept()` is called --->Line A
    }
    else
    {
      //Called when reject is called ---> Line B
    }
```

Now this method is called in `mydialog`.

```
void mydialog::someMethod()
{

    if(somecondition)
    {
        dialog_a->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
        dialog_a->setFixedSize(dialog_a->size());
        this->setVisible(false);

                if(dialog_a->exec()==1) 
                {
                   qDebug() << "Dialog A selected";
                }
                else
                {
                    //back button was pressesed
                    if(dialog_a->terminate)
                    {
                        reject();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this->setVisible(true); // --->Line C
                    }
                }
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug() << "Something else selected"; 
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem when the above method is called, it ends up in Line C. After that Line B is called. Why is that? Why is `mydialog` is exiting? I havent called `reject()` or `accept()` anywhere?
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `dialog_a`? Dialog inside of dialog class?

Comment: yes its another dialog inside the dialog. Will closing them havve any affect on the dialog that hosts them ?

Comment: Think of what happens when you hide the dialog. If `exec` didn't return at that very moment, it would *never* return since you can't interact with the dialog anymore. It's doing the only sensible thing. You asked for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line: `this->setVisible(false);`

If you look at the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/6382a038d6394135a4dc2d8e1e47133d9ea0b659:src/gui/dialogs/qdialog.cpp#L790) of `QDialog`, you can see this part:

```
    // Reimplemented to exit a modal event loop when the dialog is hidden.
    QWidget::setVisible(visible);
    if (d->eventLoop)
        d->eventLoop->exit();
```

So when `mydialog::someMethod()` returns (or whatever calls that method returns), your dialog will close.

Comment: To put it in other words: `exec` **must** return when the dialog is hidden. Otherwise it would **never** return, since you can't interact with in invisible dialog. In other words, what the asker is seeing is the only sensible behavior.